# Want to show orders notifications from orders api in React.js

Tags: reactjs, websocket, push-notification, e-commerce

I am building a warehouse management system for WordPress store in React.js: I have built an API (http://wms-api.martoo.com/api/wms-orders) for orders and fetching all the orders in my React Dashboard.

Now I want to show notification for each order in my React dashboard. What's the best approach for that to show notification automatically when someone places an order through WordPress eCommerce. Probably sockets can help but I am looking for the solution.  I will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked for different methods but non worked. I have tried webhooks, cron jobs but this method is effiecient. I have used pusher

- Go at https://pusher.com/
- Click on "Get a free account". Then register yourself at it.
- Create a new App at the Channels tab.
- Write the name of your app anything you want.
- Choose ap2 (Asia Pacific(Mumbai)) or any other closer to the region of the website's owner on the cluster tab.
- Ignore everything else and click on create.
- Go to the apps tab in the navigation menu and click on the app you've created.
- Read documentation for further instructions